# SSIS - How to easily parse yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss a.m. format

Tags: date, ssis, formatting

I need to parse a date like "22/06/2010 3:21:31 p.m." in SSIS in a data flow.

Cast(DT_DBTIMESTAMP
) does not work at this is does not handle this format.

What is the easiest way that I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have a couple of problems.  First, I don't think your date format is acceptable.  Can you change the `p.m.` to `pm` (remove the periods)?

The other possible problem is your SSIS expression.  The SSIS expression syntax would be

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)NameOfVariable
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised all I had to do was replace the periods and then cast.